# mapbox gl data driven style: What does the "value" parameter do?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm modifying my icon size based on the current zoom value by using the zoom data to drive the size.

As I understand it, I'm using the property "zoom" to track the zoom value (This is required as per the spec), In the stops I setup each desired "zoom" value and then output the icon-size value for that state (shown by the 0-1 > 3 range). If I don't include the parameter "value": *something* the code fails. If I set it all to 1, it works fine, so it seems that this value is ignored.

Can anyone explain its actual use?

```
    // Add layer to map populating data from Geojson
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "seed",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "objects",
        "layout": {
            "icon-rotation-alignment": "map",
            "icon-keep-upright": true,
            "icon-rotate": 0,
            "icon-image": "{icon}",
            "icon-allow-overlap": true,
            "icon-size": {
                "property": "zoom",
                "type": "exponential",
                "stops": [
                    [{ "zoom": 15, "value": 1}, 0.1],
                    [{ "zoom": 16, "value": 1}, 0.3],
                    [{ "zoom": 17, "value": 1}, 0.6],
                    [{ "zoom": 18, "value": 1}, 0.8],
                    [{ "zoom": 19, "value": 1}, 2],
                    [{ "zoom": 20, "value": 1}, 3]
                ]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the confusion @stuffyjoelab!

There are three types of functions in Mapbox GL:

- **Zoom functions** allow the appearance of a map feature to change with map’s zoom level
- **Property functions** allow the appearance of a map feature to change with its properties.
- **Zoom-and-property functions** allow the appearance of a map feature to change with both its properties and zoom.

[(There's more info about these in our style spec docs)](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#types-function)

> I'm using the property "zoom" to track the zoom value

We define a "property" as being per-feature metadata, a la [GeoJSON feature properties](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects). By this definition, `zoom` is not a property (unless you have a property on your features called `zoom`)

If you switch to the zoom function syntax by removing `"property": "zoom"` and replacing the `{zoom, value}` objects from your stops with numeric zooms, everything should work as expected.

```
// Add layer to map populating data from Geojson
map.addLayer({
    "id": "seed",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "objects",
    "layout": {
        "icon-rotation-alignment": "map",
        "icon-keep-upright": true,
        "icon-rotate": 0,
        "icon-image": "{icon}",
        "icon-allow-overlap": true,
        "icon-size": {
            "type": "exponential",
            "stops": [
                [15, 0.1],
                [16, 0.3],
                [17, 0.6],
                [18, 0.8],
                [19, 2],
                [20, 3]
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's the kind of stuff that you could never work out by reading the docs. Often you just need an good example ....! Your answer has suddenly answered many mysteries about geojson and mapbox, though I shall have to read it many times before it's all clear.